Powering lights of Breezer Uptown 7 2011
Just bought a used Breezer Uptown 7 out of someone's garage, and I'm trying to figure out how to wire the lights that came with the bike. Based on the color scheme, I believe I bought the 2011 model which, based on the hub specifications, does not use a dynamo hub to power the lights (as opposed to the 2016 version). In that case, it seems like the lights hook up to something which is attached to the rear triangle on the non-drive side, as can be seen in this (blurry) picture:

However, mine is missing whatever goes there, with only the mount left (taken from the non-drive side):

The lights themselves are Basta Riff Steady and Basta Sprint Steady lights, which I believe can be powered by any 6V source.
My question is: does anyone have a suggestion for something that could mount to the hole in the picture? Either a dynamo or a battery pack would be sufficient for me, I just want my lights to go.

I don’t have time for answer. That used to have a so-called “bottle dynamo” that engaged with the rear tire. Searching for one of those will be your most direct path to lighting. I prefer dynamo hubs, but that’ll be a bigger financial lift (essentially a new front wheel with an expensive hub)

As indicated in the comments, this is a mounting point for a bottle dynamo.
Those come in a simple version which allows for one wire for the front light and one for the rear light often combined into one connection on the dynamo, the return power would have to find its way through the frame and a modern version which allow for four wires, two for the front light and two for the rear.
The modern dynamos also have a bigger wheel to go against the tire.
If you can afford the modern dynamo I would go for that and the double wires for the power.
The lights you mention are dynamo lights and have a way to keep light going for a short while after you stop riding.
I used this kind of dynamos for years but once cheap battery led lights came available I made sure to always have a front and rear one of those with me as well. Dynamos will never have a spend battery but if something is wrong with the system you are without lights.
In recent years I did mostly double up, with the silicone encased led lights as the extra lights.

Do you happen to have a specific example of an old-style dynamo and a modern dynamo? My local bike shops carry neither, and I'm having trouble parsing what is reputable.

As we are in different parts of the world, no, it is very hard for me to find what is sold where you are. Maybe someone in the US can tell you what is in the market there.

A guide to the better kind is, besides that they are more expensive, is that they come in sets with double wires.
